# How to encrypt Sql Server 2008 table for security reasons?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, encryption

I have a web application in `C#` and `SQL server 2008` . For security reasons I need to fully encrypt content of few tables which contains personal details of users. I mean these tables should be in a non-readable format when viewed from `SQL server` but when authorised user view these table details from application they should be able to view the content.

i have referred to many articles on MSDN related to data encryption using symmetric encryption but I’m not sure as how to use them. Please help by suggesting ways which i can use to achieve this..

Answer (score 2):

The best way to protect data is deny direct access to tables. Use Views, SPs and Functions (triggers perhaps) to access and manipulate data in your system. This is the best practice to work with SQL DB (independently from engine).
But if you want to stay with the original concept you described, I would recommend using [Column Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx). It is also a good starting point to read through [SQL Server Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx) article.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if a table encryption is the right solution for the use case you mention.

First of all, encrypting a table is not possible. You can encrypt either a whole database or a column.

In your case I would go for a column level encryption.

**A great tutorial can be found here:** http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/

For the users not to be able to see a content of a specific table you should also set proper permissions on that table.

```
GRANT SELECT ON Customers TO UserName
```

This way only the user will be able to read from the table.